# How would it be better to LOOP a jquery function?

Tags: jquery, performance, for-loop, show-hide

I'm trying to understand a bit more of jQuery and how it works.
[In my last Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993134/how-to-show-2-or-more-div-based-of-radio-selection-with-jquery/) user Zachary Kniebel helped me figure how to show/hide some values based on a 'RADIO' form, now I modified his code and I would like to improve it a more using a loop (maybe a FOR loop as he suggested to me).
Actually I had no luck so here is my question:

**

### I forgot to say that I can't change HTML because it is automatically generated by a wordpress Option framework...

**

How is it possible to use a LOOP for this function without changing the HTML part?

**[For jsfiddle lovers here it is a working example with really long js CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/downloadtaky/4aCtP/9/)**

> JS

--

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $types = $('.of-radio');
    $types.change(function () {
        $this = $(this).val();
        if ($this == "0") {
            /* zone 1 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n1').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n1').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n1').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n1').hide();
            /* end zone 1 start zone 2*/
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n2').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n2').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n2').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n2').hide();
            /* end zone 2 start zone 3 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n3').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n3').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n3').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n3').hide();
            /* end zone 3 start zone 4 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n4').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n4').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n4').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n4').hide();
            /* end zone 4 start zone 5 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n5').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n5').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n5').hide();            
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n5').hide();
            /* end zone 5 */
        } else if ($this == "1") {
            /* start zone 1 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n1').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n1').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n1').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n1').show();
            /* end zone 1 start zone 2 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n2').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n2').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n2').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n2').hide();
            /* end zone 2 start zone 3 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n3').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n3').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n3').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n3').hide();
            /* end zone 3 start zone 4 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n4').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n4').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n4').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n4').hide();
            /* end zone 4 start zone 5 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n5').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n5').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n5').hide();            
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n5').hide();
            /* end zone 5 */
        } else if ($this == "2") {
            /* start zone 1 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n1').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n1').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n1').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n1').show();
            /* end zone 1 start zone 2 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n2').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n2').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n2').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n2').show();
            /* end zone 2 start zone 3 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n3').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n3').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n3').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n3').hide();
            /* end zone 3 start zone 4 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n4').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n4').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n4').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n4').hide();
            /* end zone 4 start zone 5 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n5').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n5').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n5').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n4').hide();
            /* end zone 5 */
        } else if ($this == "3") {
            /*start zone 1 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n1').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n1').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n1').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n1').show();
            /* end zone 1 start zone 2 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n2').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n2').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n2').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n2').show();
            /* end zone 2 start zone 3 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n3').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n3').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n3').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n3').show();
            /* end zone 3 start zone 4 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n4').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n4').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n4').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n4').hide();
            /* end zone 4 start zone 5 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n5').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n5').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n5').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n5').hide();
            /* end zone 5 */
        } else if ($this == "4") {
            /* start zone 1 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n1').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n1').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n1').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n1').show();
            /* end zone 1 start zone 2 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n2').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n2').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n2').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n2').show();
            /* end zone 2 start zone 3 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n3').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n3').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n3').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n3').show();
            /* end zone 3 start zone 4 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n4').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n4').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n4').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n4').show();
            /* end zone 4 start zone 5 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n5').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n5').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n5').hide();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n5').hide();
            /* end zone 5 */
        } else if ($this == "5") {
            /* start zone 1 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n1').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n1').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n1').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n1').show();
            /* end zone 1 start zone 2 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n2').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n2').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n2').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n2').show();
            /* end zone 2 start zone 3 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n3').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n3').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n3').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n3').show();
            /* end zone 3 start zone 4 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n4').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n4').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n4').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n4').show();
            /* end zone 4 start zone 5 */
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n5').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n5').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n5').show();
            $('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n5').show();
            /* end zone 5 */
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: (O.T) you came here right in time ;)

Comment: Does "cicle" mean "loop"?

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, I mean LOOP not cicle :P sorry for bad english and... I can't change HTML because it is generated by a WordPress Option Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how efficient this is but this is the shortest I was able to get the code down to. I'm not sure if you are looking for efficiency or shortest way possible. Like everyone else I used loops and chaining built into jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $types = $('.of-radio');
    $types.change(function () {
       /* $(".section").not("#section-how_many_custom_posts").hide();*/
        $this = $(this).val();
        $('[id^="section-custom_posts_name_"]').hide().each(function(i, val)
                  {
                      if($this > 0 && i < ($this * 4) && $(val).attr('id').replace( /^\D+/g, '') <= $this)
                          $(val).show();
                  });
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/downloadtaky/4aCtP/9/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, actually it seems working and I'm studying your solution to be able to replicate it in future. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

**First thing** to simplify is to put another div around each group of related divs.

```
<div id="section-custom_posts_name_all_n1">
    ... existing set of 4 divs for s, n, i and p and related text for n1 ...
</div>
```

Then instead of

```
$('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n1').hide();
$('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n1').hide();
$('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n1').hide();
$('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n1').hide();
```

You just put:

```
$('#section-custom_posts_name_all_n1').hide();
```

**Second thing** thing to simplify is that you can build the strings up with concatenation:

```
for (int i=1; i <= last  ; ++i) {
    $("#section-custom_posts_name_all_n" + i).hide();
}
```

This will hide all of them up to a point defined by `last`.

**Third thing** is to turn it around and do it this way (plus use a loop):

```
$this = parseInt($(this).val())
for (var i=1; i < 6 ; ++i) {
            fixDisplay($('#section-custom_posts_name_s_n'+i), $this, i);
            fixDisplay($('#section-custom_posts_name_p_n'+i), $this, i);
            fixDisplay($('#section-custom_posts_name_i_n'+i), $this, i);
            fixDisplay($('#section-custom_posts_name_d_n'+i), $this, i);
}

function fixDisplay($el, val, section) {
    if (section <= val) {
        $el.show();
    } else {
        $el.hide();
    }
};
```

Comment: I just modified my answer because I forgot to write that I can't change the HTML part because it is automatically generated by: http://wptheming.com/options-framework-theme/

Comment: Then you can only use the 2nd thing.

Comment: I don't think that even second thing will work because it will require to modify the #ID of a selector... and I can't :(

Comment: The example in the 2nd thing won't work but the idea of concatenating to form the selector for jQuery ... that still works.

Comment: :-) Ok, I'll try to use it to get to a solution, thank you. Maybe I'll need a cup of coffee more, in Italy it's almost 2 AM.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean `loop`, not `cicle`.

But you don't even need a loop, you can handle everything in CSS and just use `class` names on your elements and reduce this code to:

HTML:

```
<div id="myParentDiv" class="show_0">
    <div class="block_1">...</div>
    <div class="block_2">...</div>
    <div class="block_3">...</div>
    <div class="block_4">...</div>
    <div class="block_5">...</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $types = $('.of-radio');
    $types.change(function () {
        $this = $(this).val();

        $('#myParentDiv').removeClass('show_0 show_1 show_2 show_3 show_4 show_5');

        if ($this == "0") {
            $('#myParentDiv').addClass('show_0');
        } else if ($this == "1") {
            $('#myParentDiv').addClass('show_1');
        } else if ($this == "2") {
            $('#myParentDiv').addClass('show_2');
        } else if ($this == "3") {
            $('#myParentDiv').addClass('show_3');
        } else if ($this == "4") {
            $('#myParentDiv').addClass('show_4');
        } else if ($this == "5") {
            $('#myParentDiv').addClass('show_5');
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.block_1,
.block_2,
.block_3,
.block_4,
.block_5 {
    display: none;
}

.show_1 .block_1 {
    display: block;
}
.show_2 .block_1,
.show_2 .block_2 {
    display: block;
}
.show_3 .block_1,
.show_3 .block_2,
.show_3 .block_3 {
    display: block;
}
.show_4 .block_1,
.show_4 .block_2,
.show_4 .block_3,
.show_4 .block_4 {
    display: block;
}
.show_5 .block_1,
.show_5 .block_2,
.show_5 .block_3,
.show_5 .block_4,
.show_5 .block_5 {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: He's is showing elements 1-n and not just element n. You need 6 `if`s and to use less than. Also 0 means show none.

Comment: I wrote cicle but I meant LOOP (sorry for this...)
and... I can't change the HTML part because it is automatically generated by a WP option frameworK: http://wptheming.com/options-framework-theme/